# combine word and pdf files together and convert to tiff

Tags: pdf

I have several folders.  Each folder contains some pdf files and word files.  Is there a tool (free/commercial) that anyone can recommend that can go through each of the folders and create a single combined pdf file for each of the folders?  It will also have to convert the word document to pdf before it can merge.

Pratik

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDF Burger to combine files into PDF - http://pdfburger.com/combine-to-pdf

Is is a free service.

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for.    
But the address has changed to [https://docs.zone/combine-to-pdf](https://docs.zone/combine-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Convert pdf to text and then merge it word and then to pdf. I am aware of a called `pdf2text` on linux (Ubuntu). I guess that should do the job for you.

-Pradeep

[See here](http://tech.pradeepnayak.in/?p=183)